# Java verbose GC log configuration - file not being created

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection, g1gc

I've tried to configure in both eclipse and intelliJ arguments with garbage collection logger for simple test program.
Tried different kind of configurations and the log file has not been created.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:gc.log
```

The garbage collection I prefer to create log from is G1 if possible.

Comment: Are you receiving any output at all? What JDK are using? Some of the GC logging options have changed quite a bit starting in Java 9: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-notes-3745703.html#JDK-8145092

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-X` or `-XX` params are VM options and not program arguments, which makes me think that if you did not get any errors you may have it incorrectly passed to your program.

I get the following when using your params:

> Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'

By removing it, it worked fine and generated `gc.log`.

**Via IDE**

[image]

**Via Command Line**

```
$ java -Xloggc:gc.log com/stackoverflow/Main
```

---

**-Xloggc is deprecated**

*<= Java 8* `-Xloggc:filename.log`

*>= Java 9* `-Xlog:gc:filename.log`

Using `-Xloggc` with a modern JVM still works but gives a warning:

> [0.005s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:gc.log instead.